# How can i download only new records from Anviz EP300?

Tags: c#-4.0, device, biometrics

All,

Currently i'm using Anviz EP300 time attendance machine. I need to download only new records from device.

I'm using following sdk. [Click here](http://www.files.com/set/5205aeeb584ce)

There is some method already have in sdk. Which is i used like...

```
int i = 0;
        int Ret = 0;
        int RecordCount = 0;
        int RetCount = 0;
        int pClockings = 0;
        int pLongRun = 0;
        CKT_DLL.CLOCKINGRECORD clocking = new CKT_DLL.CLOCKINGRECORD();
        clocking.Time = new byte[20];

        int ptemp = 0;
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0;

        //If CKT_GetClockingNewRecordEx(IDNumber, pLongRun) Then 'IF GET NewRecord
        if (CKT_DLL.CKT_GetClockingNewRecordEx(IDNumber, ref pLongRun) != 0) //IF GET Record
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Ret = CKT_DLL.CKT_GetClockingRecordProgress(pLongRun, ref RecordCount, ref RetCount, ref pClockings);
                if (RecordCount > 0)
                {
                    ProgressBar1.Maximum = RecordCount;
                }
                if (Ret == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (Ret != 0)
                {
                    ptemp = pClockings;

                    for (i = 1; i <= RetCount; i++)
                    {
                        PCopyMemory(ref clocking, pClockings, CKT_DLL.CLOCKINGRECORDSIZE);
                        pClockings = pClockings + CKT_DLL.CLOCKINGRECORDSIZE;

                        insertTimeAttendance(clocking.PersonID, clocking.Stat, Encoding.Default.GetString(clocking.Time), clocking.ID);

                        ProgressBar1.Value += 1;
                    }

                    if (ptemp != 0)
                    {
                        CKT_DLL.CKT_FreeMemory(ptemp);
                    }
                }

                if (Ret == 1)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

CKT_GetClockingNewRecordEx that method should be return new records. But it returns all records.

I guess, there is should be one method or config should be mark as downloaded.

Anyone some idea or solution?

Thanks,
Eba

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? Me too facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created the SDK you downloaded (basically written in Vb, and I just convert it to C#)
Actually for the Anviz EP300 device, there is no way you can just retrieve new records,neither retrieve user lists (for example), at list with that SDK.. It has a lot of methods, but unfortunately few of them works fine. You will have to Use **CKT_GetClockingRecordEx**, instead of **CKT_DLL.CKT_GetClockingNewRecordEx**